# Geolocation IP in Java

Tags: java, geolocation, ip

Is there any way to get the country, city (generally: geolocation information) from IP address. Note that my application is java.

I visisted and tried many web services, but I didn't find suitable one and I prefer to write my own. Also, I found some CSV DBs but also this solution is not preferable at all. please, help.

Comment: You can probably do it, but your results will be approximate. The fact is, I can spread my servers out all over the world; you'll have no way to know my internal topology.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is [GeoIP](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/), provided by MaxMind company.

They provide [free GeoIP2 database - GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) and several [GeoIP2 APIs](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/#MaxMind_APIs)(thanks karel) including Java API to read database file too.

- [Documents](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/)
- [Java API](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-java/doc/v2.1.0/overview-summary.html)
- [Downloadable Java libraries](https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-java/releases)
- [Downloadable Java libraries from maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|com.maxmind), my favorite :), you need download both [com.maxmind.db](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.maxmind.db%22) and [com.maxmind.geoip2](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.maxmind.geoip2%22).

Before GeoIP2, there was GeoIP, now they called it [GeoIP Lecacy](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/), [Free databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) and [downloadable Java library from maven.org](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22com.maxmind.geoip%22) or [from github](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-java/releases) are still available.

GeoIP Lecacy maybe dead in the future, however, for now, because GeoIP2 doesn't provide Java API to read the database information (such as **GEO-533LITE 20150303 Build 1 Copyright (c) 2015 MaxMind Inc All Rights Reserved**), so I still use it in my website. I use GeoIP2 in my IRC bot to benefit from the multiple language feature of GeoIP2.

Comment: Thanks. But I really don't prefer such solutions. I would like to know if there is any way that I can write this in my Java code.

Comment: I don't think you can use pure java code to *calculate* it's geo location, there must be some databases (file or relational) behind it. Even GIS system has underlying databases (like POI database)

Answer (score 0):

Each country has a few range of IPs.

I'm not aware of a Java implementation of that, but you could use the output from http://services.ce3c.be/ciprg/ and create your own code that gives the country based upon the IP address.