# Try to Find geolocation using ip

Tags: java

```
File dbfile = new File("D:/jar/Geo/GeoLiteCity.dat");
LookupService lookupService = null;
    try {
        lookupService = new LookupService(dbfile,  LookupService.GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


Location location = null;
    try {

        location = lookupService.getLocation(InetAddress.getByName("180.215.123.30"));
      location.region = regionName.regionNameByCode(location.countryCode, location.region);
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

if (location != null) {
System.out.println(location.region = regionName.regionNameByCode(location.countryCode, location.region));
```

}
    }

I browse and try the code.it print null.Any guidence to find geo location.using ipaddress.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is what you want, but take a look at it: [Geolocation IP in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138071/geolocation-ip-in-java)

Comment: thank you for replay.i just go to the link .that shows (We're sorry. You've reached a destination that doesn't exist.) https://www.maxmind.com/en/java .i try to find city code or name using java.i download GeoLiteCity database.and where to get java library or any code tutorial clearly.

Comment: I'm sorry about the broken link. I told LiuYan 刘研 about the broken link in his answer, and he has completely updated [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138071/geolocation-ip-in-java/11138170#11138170), including a new link to the Java API.